# No mostrar un @include en vista especifica Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Buenas tardes tengo un layout con todo el código que muestro en todas las vistas, pero hay una parte que es un `@inlcude(includes.menu)`. Hay alguna posibilidad de en una vista en concreto no mostrarlo? he mirado documentación y Google, y o no busco bien o no lo encuentro.

Saludos

Comment: claro, puedes usar las directivas `@if @endif` y de acuerdo a la condición que quieras, agregar ese include u obviarlo.

Comment: Hola @gaidyjg agradeceria una respuesta más concreta, no se que comprobar con un `@if`

Comment: Tu pregunta es bastante vaga. Por eso supuse que con eso bastaría. Por ejemplo, si quieres evaluar tu request, podrías hacer `@if(request()->segment(0) === 'path')` muestras tu includes, de resto, pues no. Suponiendo que _path_ sea una ruta que exista dentro de tu request. Eso te mostraría tu menú o no.

Comment: Quizas si me explique mal. Tengo un include que es un menú, pero en una vista en concreto no quiero que se muestre, no se como poder utilizar un `request` ahí

Comment: bueno, ¿cómo sería tu ruta que muestra esa vista y no quieres que se vea? Así te plasmo un ejemplo mejor como respuesta concreta

Comment: Seria esta, puede tener dos condiciones por eso `{contrato}` y  la ruta es esta: `/subscribe/{contrato}`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122598/discussion-between-gaidyjg-and-miguel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En los templates de blade de Laravel, se pueden usar también las [condicionales](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements), además de los helpers que Laravel provee para manejar rutas como: [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request) o [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing), podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
@if(! request()->segment(1) === 'subscribe')
    @includes('includes.menu')
@endif
```

O usando Route:

```
@if(! Route::is('subscribe'))
    @includes('includes.menu')
@endif
```

Y eso debería de dejar mostrar tu menú mientras esté en esa ruta.

Espero te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfectamente!!!